# How to get post request data using slim?

Tags: php, sql, post, slim

It is a simple crud application with slim framework I am using mysql database... slim version is 2.6.2. Mysql version is 5.7.8

Image of postman:

[image]

```
// Adds a customer
function addCustomer() {
    //$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $cus = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (Username,First_Name,Last_Name,Email,Phone,Password,Type,Status) VALUES (:username, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :password, :type, :status)";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        
        $stmt->bindParam("username", $cus->Username);
        $stmt->bindParam("firstname", $cus->First_Name);
        $stmt->bindParam("lastname", $cus->Last_Name);
        $stmt->bindParam("email", $cus->Email);
        $stmt->bindParam("phone", $cus->Phone);
        $stmt->bindParam("password", $cus->Password);
        $stmt->bindParam("type", $cus->Type);
        $stmt->bindParam("status", $cus->Status);
        $stmt->execute();
        $cus->id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($cus); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

[image]

[image: Get request is working fine]

Get request is working fine:

Comment: Probably you are passing a empty $cus->Username.

Comment: yep I also think that

Comment: After `$cus = json_decode($request->getBody());` can you please post the output `var_dump($cus)`

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\slim\a.php:66:null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're missing is the colon before the parameter on the bind statements. You should correct to:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $cus->Username);
$stmt->bindParam(":firstname", $cus->First_Name);
$stmt->bindParam(":lastname", $cus->Last_Name);
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $cus->Email);
$stmt->bindParam(":phone", $cus->Phone);
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $cus->Password);
$stmt->bindParam(":type", $cus->Type);
$stmt->bindParam(":status", $cus->Status);
```

**EDIT**

Actually now that I took a deeper look, you're passing the params with lowercase first letter (take a look at the Postman screenshot, you used username, but in your code, you're trying to assign Username). Just put a capitalized "Username" as a post field to Postman, or replace as follows:

```
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $cus->username);
$stmt->bindParam(":firstname", $cus->firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(":lastname", $cus->lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $cus->email);
$stmt->bindParam(":phone", $cus->phone);
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $cus->password);
$stmt->bindParam(":type", $cus->type);
$stmt->bindParam(":status", $cus->status);
```

**EDIT II**

replace all binding with the following loop:

```
foreach($request->params() as $key => $val) {
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $val);
}
```

Comment: The driver auto adds the colon, if not present.

Comment: I replace your bind statements, but still I got the same error

Comment: That's because the driver adds the `:` automatically. This answer adds nothing. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3.24/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L363 (although for future compatibility you should have the `:`, that feature isn't in the manual)

Comment: $stmt->bindParam("Username", $cus->Username);  gives me {"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined}}

Comment: Yes I also try that... that gives me same error as before: {"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Username' cannot be null}}
I am restarting all my services before each test

Comment: The next thing that I saw - you're trying to json_decode non json request. Why don't you just remove json_decode, and maybe print the value of $cus to see what it contains?

Comment: In either way, lowercase must remain as I mentioned.

Comment: It says: 

------WebKitFormBoundaryzLSkmi5TFcOaPh3W Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username" asdasdsdasd ------WebKitFormBoundaryzLSkmi5TFcOaPh3W Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstname" fnsdlfnfn ------
More text~ and after that an error Type: ErrorException
Code: 2
Message: Attempt to modify property of non-object

Comment: The error of slim starts when is made the $stmt->bindParam(":username", $cus->username);

Comment: Ok Ill try it in a few hours Ill keep yoy noticed

Answer (score 1):

I think $cus->Username you are trying to insert is empty.Try to use $stmt->bindValue instead of $stmt->bindParam.

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: I get a familiar error like the previous one: Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Have you printed the username value?

Comment: cus is ------WebKitFormBoundaryBPY0dQWuXnIQRZhT Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username" asdasdsdasd ------WebKitFormBoundaryBPY0dQWuXnIQRZhT-- Before making the 
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $cus->username);

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case sensitivity issue. You're binding parameters from the form attempting to reference them by their counterpart database column names. Your postman screenshot shows the input names are all lowercase.

Try

```
    $stmt->bindParam("username", $cus->username);
    $stmt->bindParam("firstname", $cus->firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam("lastname", $cus->lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam("email", $cus->email);
    $stmt->bindParam("phone", $cus->phone);
    $stmt->bindParam("password", $cus->password);
    $stmt->bindParam("type", $cus->type);
    $stmt->bindParam("status", $cus->status);
```

Comment: Ok.. making the request as before with postman and with your code still gives me the same error.. {"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Username' cannot be null}} thanks..